# Show a beam is in equilibrium given the stress tensor

Tags: physics, tensors

Having some trouble with this:

https://gyazo.com/0835bdaa8e01cb976765aac94555f6ef

I know how to show that at x_2 = -h the surface traction is zero, but I'm not sure how to show it's in equilibrium? Not sure how to get the forces to equate. 
Same problem with part (ii), not sure how to derive the forces.

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. just a suggestion preferably we'd have you type the problem to avoid having to click through to help you. Also an explicit statement of what you tried and where and what ideas you have had is preferable as well as a specific question.

Comment: Do you know the equilibrium condition for the continuum's stress tensor?

Comment: is that d(stress)_ij/dx_i = 0 ? @ccorn

Comment: Yes, if you sum over $i$. (That's the static version without body forces.)

Comment: @ccorn I used that on the information given and it gives a long equation, shouldn't it equal 0 in an equilibrium?

Comment: It should give 3 expressions identical to $0$. If that does not work out for you, better show in the question what you get instead.

Comment: This is not mathematical physics. Retagged.